# How to make vim point to a syntax file located at a custom path

Tags: linux, vim

I'm trying to add a custom syntax highlighting file mysyn.vim in the syntax library of vim. Unfortunately, as I'm not the administrator I don't have access to `usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax` space. Hence, I was wondering if there is a way I can place the syntax file in my local area `/home/doug/mysyn.vim` and make vim look at this file by editing the `.vimrc` (.vimrc file is in my local space as well).

To get over this problem, I also considered copying my entire vim directory from `usr/share/vim` to `/home/doug/myvim/` and change the default runtime path of vim. I tried doing this by adding the line `let $VIMRUNTIME=\home\doug\myvimfiles\` to the .vimrc file. However, I get an error saying `VIMRUNTIME : Undefined variable`

So, are there any suggestions of how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a decently recent version of Vim you can just create a directory `~/.vim/syntax` and put syntax files there.  You seem to be running Vim 7.2 though, which is some 8 years old.  Getting your sysadmin sacked might be the better choice. :)

Comment: `~/.vim/syntax` should work even in Vim 6.x; it definitely works down to Vim 7.0. There hasn't been that much change in all the years...